# Stripe - 'Send Test Webhook' working but not logged in 'Webhook Attempts' list

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe API and webhooks to link payments to my website. I have a webhook listener at `https://mywebsite.com/hook.php`. When I send a test webhook through Stripe's developer dashboard, I receive my expected response of `hello world`.

[image]

However, in my list of webhook attempts, this request was not logged (this request was sent ~2 hours after the last request on this list.

[image]

Here is my PHP webhook code:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_CHANGEDFORTHISSOQUESTION"); //test

// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$payload = @file_get_contents("php://input");

// Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
http_response_code(200);
echo("hello world");
$endpoint_secret = "whsec_CHANGEDFORTHISSOQUESTION"; //test
$sig_header = $_SERVER["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"];
$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );

    // Do something with $event_json

} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
  // Invalid payload
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
  // Invalid signature
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's normal and that the "Webhook attempts" table is only meant to show actual event deliveries. Sending the dummy event data from the test button is just an ad-hoc action for testing, it wouldn't appear there.

Comment: Really? Well damn thats misleading!